# CentOS ./configure -- how to use alternate PHP version

Tags: php, centos, xdebug

I am quite new to CentOS.
On my CentOS web server I have PHP 5.4.16 as a native PHP version though I also have alternate PHP version 7.0. 
I am trying to install xDebug for PHP 7.0 following the instruction on https://xdebug.org and one of the steps is to run

```
./configure
```

When I run ./configure command I am getting error message:

> not supported. Need a PHP version >= 5.5.0 and < 7.2.0 (found 5.4.16)

So my question is how do I tell ./configure to use alternate PHP version 7.0?

Answer (score 1):

If you run `php -v` on command line, it will output the version of PHP it is currently on your PATH. My guess is that it will return the older version of PHP as the result.

The quick and dirty way to try and get it to use version 7.0 for your current shell session would be to run the following

```
set PATH="/your/path/to/php7/bin:$PATH"
php -v
//Should output version 7.0
```

You could also try checking in `/usr/bin` or `/usr/local/bin` to see exactly which PHP binary it's pointing to, and manually change the location that the symlinks are pointing to.

Another option would be to try creating an alias in your `~/.bashrc` file for PHP by editing the file and adding the following to the end:

```
alias php="/your/path/to/php/7/bin/php"
```

Then restart your shell session (i.e. close an & re-open PuTTY or whichever SSH client you're using).

Now type `php -v` and you should see it change to version 7.0.